# imacro filter spaces from string var

Tags: javascript, regex, imacros

i have a string var

```
1111 2222 3333 4444
```

and i want to clear the spaces and return

```
11112222233334444
```

im trying to use

```
SET !VAR1 EVAL(" parseFloat(\"{{!VAR2}}\") ")
```

but it just returns 1, i found the following example, but trying to change USD into /\s/g isn't working for me

```
SET !VAR1 EVAL("var s=\"{{!VAR2}}\"; s.replace(\"USD\",\"\"); ")
```

js

```
string.replace(/\s/g, "");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `split` and `join`

```
var str = '1111 2222 3333 4444';
alert(str.split(' ').join(''))
```

Comment: perfect, exactly the type of answer i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

replace also should work:

```
string.replace(/ /g, "");
```